# How to use Math.NET Neodym Signal Processing Library to Filter Frequencies?

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, digital

I have streaming continuous data that I need to filter by frequency. I have high-level knowledge of FFT and frequency filtering, but no real practical knowledge.

After searching for a suitable library to aid me, I came across Math.NET's Neodym Signal Processing Library (https://mathnetneodym.codeplex.com/releases/view/91769)

I downloaded it, upgraded it to VS2010 and used the SignalGenerator class to generate various sine wave of various frequencies. It worked great.

Now, I need to know how to filter dynamic data. This StackOverflow question seems to come the closest to mine, and is a good start:
[Filtering continuous data, how to get rid of transients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184422/filtering-continuous-data-how-to-get-rid-of-transients)

There is a .chm file in the downloaded project, but it seems to just be the API documentation. I need some high-level help just pointing me in the right direction to use the library.

Can anybody provide a good resource to refer to so I can use this library for my purpose?

Thank you!

### John

UPDATE

I'm pretty sure I use the OnlineFilter.CreateBandpass static function with the mode ImpulseResponse.Infinite... but I'll post whatever I find out.

Comment: To answer your question it would be nice to know what filtering job you want to do. E.g. what are your requirements?

Comment: Specifically I need to narrow down the frequency to a band between 15 and 23 Hz.  I believe I need to use the MathNet.SignalProcessing.Filter.OnlineFilter.CreateBandPass method, and I do believe I should plug in 15 and 23 for the low and high cutoff rates, but the order confuses me. The default seems 4 for Infinite Response, and 64 for Finite Response. I don't know which to use and was just going to experiment. Does it look like I'm on the right track?